# Using an Equation from another Equation based on **kwargs

Tags: python, python-2.x

What my code does is that it takes input as to which function to use, and then plugs in the appropriate data in to the given function.

For example:

- User input: force(1, density = 10.0, volume = 5.0)
- Result: 490.5

The 1 is the equation ID, and the rest are user parameters

```
import Constants as C
import Errors as E

def force_bouyant( density , volume ):
    '''Returns the Buoyant Force Given Density and Volume'''
    return C.F_GRAVITY * density * volume



def force_centripetal( mass , velocity, radius ):
    '''Returns the Centripetal Force Given Mass, Velocity, and Radius'''
    return ( ( mass * velocity * velocity ) / float(radius) )



def force_electrical( q1, q2, radius ):
    '''Returns the Electrical Attraction Force Given the Charges of the Two        Particles, and the Distance Between Them'''
    if radius == 0:
        raise E.InputError("Radius Cannot Be Zero")
    else:
        top = C.K_CONSTANT * q1 * q2
        return ( top / float( radius * radius ) )



def force_friction( nForce , Rcoeff ):
      '''Returns the Force of Friction Given the Normal Force, and the  Coefficient of Friction'''
      return ( nForce * Rcoeff)
def force_friction_nNF( mass , Rcoeff):
    '''Returns the Force of Friction When the Normal Force isn't Given, but Mass is'''
    return ( mass * C.F_GRAVITY * Rcoeff )


def force_given_ma( mass , acceleration ):
    '''Returns the Force Given the Mass and the Acceleration'''
    return ( mass * acceleration )



def force_given_pt( momentum , time ):
    '''Returns the Force Given the Change in Momentum and the Change in Time'''
    return ( momentum / float(time) )



def force_gravity( mass1, mass2, radius ):
    '''Returns the Force of Gravity Given the Masses of the two Objects, and the Distance Between Them'''
    top = ( C.GRAV_CONSTANT * mass1 * mass2 )
    return ( -top / float( radius ) )



def force(equation_id, **kwargs):
    '''
    Returns the Force with the Kwargs being the Type of Force Equation

    Valid arguments are as follows:

        equation:

            1 : Bouyant Force ( d * V * g )
            2 : Centripetal Force (( m * v^2 ) / r)
            3 : Electrical Force (( k * q1 * q2 ) / ( r * r )
            4 : Force of Gravity (( G * m1 * m2 ) / r)
            5 : Force of Friction (Fn * cF)
            6 : Mass * Acceleration
            7 : Delta Momentum / Delta Time

        **kwargs

            fields:     (Don't type in field, type in the actual field name)

                acceleration
                charge
                charge2 (For more than 1 charge)
                density
                friction_coefficient
                mass
                mass2 (For more than 1 mass)
                momentum
                normal_force
                radius
                time
                velocity
                volume

    '''
    accel   =         kwargs.get( 'acceleration' , 0 )
    charge  =         kwargs.get( 'charge' , 0 )
    charge2 =         kwargs.get( 'charge2' , 0 )
    dense   =         kwargs.get( 'density' , 0 )
    fcoeff  =         kwargs.get( 'friction_coefficient' , 0 )
    mass    =         kwargs.get( 'mass' , 0 )
    mass2   =         kwargs.get( 'mass2', 0 )
    moment  =         kwargs.get( 'momentum' , 0 )
    nForce  =         kwargs.get( 'normal_force' , 0 )
    radius  =         kwargs.get( 'radius' , 0 )
    time    =         kwargs.get( 'time' , 0 )
    veloc   =         kwargs.get( 'velocity' , 0 )
    volume  =         kwargs.get( 'volume' , 0 )

    if equation_id == 1:
        ret = force_bouyant( dense , volume )
    elif equation_id == 2:
        ret = force_centripetal( mass, veloc, radius )
    elif equation_id == 3:
        ret = force_electrical( charge , charge2, radius )
    elif equation_id == 4:
        ret = force_gravity( mass , mass2 , radius )
    elif equation_id == 5:
        if ( ( nForce == 0 ) and ( mass != 0 ) ):
            ret = force_friction_nNF( mass , fcoeff )
        elif ( nForce != 0 ):
            ret = force_friction( nForce , fcoeff )
        else:
            raise E.InputError("No Normal Force Data was input")
    elif equation_id == 6:
        ret = force_given_ma( mass, accel )
    elif equation_id == 7:
        ret = force_given_pt( moment , time )
    else:
        raise E.InputError("Invalid or No Equation Input")
    return ret
```

I was wondering if this is a good way to store/use equations, or if there is a better way to catalog equations.

Comment: Your indentation didn't make sense. Please check that Rev 4 accurately conveys your intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are loads of options on how to store and execute equations, and here is one version where you are able to remove all of those `if`/`elif` blocks, and where the check of arguments/fields is moved into each  equation function.

The full code is as follows:

```
class Constants:
    F_GRAVITY = 9
    GRAV_CONSTANT = 10

C = Constants()

def find_missing_argument(field_list, **fields):
    """Find the missing argument from fields, and return this or None.

    Loop through all expected fields from <field_list>, and check if they
    are present in passed field arguments, <fields>. If more than one is 
    missing, raise an error with all missing arguments. If noone is missing 
    then return None to indicate that all are present, and if just one is
    missing, then return the name of the missing argument
    """
    missing_arguments = [field for field in field_list if field not in fields]

    count_of_missing_arguments = len(missing_arguments)

    if count_of_missing_arguments > 1:
       raise AttributeError('Too many missing arguments - {}'.format(', '.join(missing_arguments)))

    elif count_of_missing_arguments == 1:
       return missing_arguments[0]

    else:
       return None


def force_buyant(**fields):
    '''Buoyant Force Given Density and Volume'''
    missing_argument = find_missing_argument(['density', 'volume'], **fields)

    # This equations expects all arguments
    if missing_argument is not None:
        raise AttributeError('Missing argument in force_buyant - {}'.format(missing_argument))

    density = fields['density']
    volume = fields['volume']

    return C.F_GRAVITY * density * volume


def force_centripetal( mass , velocity, radius ):
    '''Centripetal Force Given Mass, Velocity, and Radius'''
    return ( ( mass * velocity * velocity ) / float(radius) )


def force_friction(**fields):
    '''Force of Friction based upon normal force, friction coefficient and mass'''
    missing_argument = find_missing_argument(['normal_force',
                                              'friction_coefficient',
                                              'mass'], **fields)

    # This function expects one missing argument, and will calculate that one
    if missing_argument is None:
        raise AttributeError('Found all fields, don\'t know what to do'.format(missing_argument))

    # Do calculations
    if missing_argument is 'mass':
        return fields['normal_force'] * fields['friction_coefficient']

    elif missing_argument is 'normal_force':
        return fields['mass'] * C.F_GRAVITY * fields['friction_coefficient']



def force_friction_v2(**fields):
    '''Force of Friction based upon normal force, friction coefficient and mass'''
    missing_argument = find_missing_argument(['normal_force',
                                              'friction_coefficient',
                                              'mass'], **fields)

    # This function expects one missing argument, and will calculate that one
    if missing_argument is None:
        raise AttributeError('Found all fields, don\'t know what to do'.format(missing_argument))

    # set local variables (to increase readability in formulas)

    normal_force = fields.get('normal_force', None)
    friction_coefficient = fields.get('friction_coefficient', None)
    mass = fields.get('mass', None)


    # Do calculations
    if mass is None:
        return normal_force * friction_coefficient

    elif normal_force is None:
        return mass * C.F_GRAVITY * friction_coefficient


def force_friction_v3(friction_coefficient, normal_force = None, mass=None):
    '''Force of Friction based upon normal force, friction coefficient and mass'''

    if normal_force is None and friction_coefficient is None:
       raise AttributeError('Too many none arguments in force_friction_v3');

    # Do calculations
    if mass is None:
        return normal_force * friction_coefficient

    elif normal_force is None:
        return mass * C.F_GRAVITY * friction_coefficient


EQUATIONS = {
   1 : force_buyant,
   2 : force_centripetal,
   3 : force_friction,
   4 : force_friction_v2,
   5 : force_friction_v3,
}


def force(equation_id, **kwargs):

    try:
        print('{} = {}'.format(EQUATIONS[equation_id].__name__, EQUATIONS[equation_id](**kwargs)))
    except AttributeError as error:
        print('Error: {}'.format(error))
    except KeyError:
        print('Error: Invalid equation id - {}'.format(equation_id))


def main():

    # OK, called with correct arguments
    force(1, density=10, volume=20)

    # Controlled FAIL, missing volume
    force(1, density=10)

    # Controlled FAIL, multiple wrong arguments for force_buyant
    force(1, mass=10, velocity=20, radius=30)

    # OK, two version of calling force_friction with no mass
    force(3, normal_force=10, friction_coefficient=20)
    force(4, normal_force=10, friction_coefficient=20)
    force(5, normal_force=10, friction_coefficient=20)

    # Controlled FAIL, Non-existing equation id
    force(10)

    # 2 OK + 1 FAIL, one missing parameter no direct checking
    force(5, normal_force=10, friction_coefficient=20)
    force(5, mass=10, friction_coefficient=20)
    force(5, normal_force=10, mass=20)

    # Lucky break (OK), correct arguments for  force_centripetal
    force(2, mass=10, velocity=20, radius=30)

    # FAIL, wrong arguments for force_centripetal
    force(2, mass=10, velocity=20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Let us focus on some of the code presented here:

- *`main()`* – I've run some test cases to document how the different call scenarios could look like, which I hope is not too far from how you are going to call your code. The output is:

```
force_buyant = 1800
Error: Missing argument in force_buyant - volume
Error: Too many missing arguments - density, volume
force_friction = 200
force_friction_v2 = 200
force_friction_v3 = 200
Error: Invalid equation id - 10
force_friction_v3 = 200
force_friction_v3 = 1800
TypeError - force_friction_v3() takes at least 1 argument (2 given)
force_centripetal = 133.333333333
TypeError - force_centripetal() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

- `find_missing_argument()` - This is the hub of checking for missing arguments. You provide the full list of fields to be expected, and it checks if they are present. If none or just one is missing, it's considered OK and this is returned. If more than one is missing an error is raised. This allows for specification of all fields related to a formula, and testing for all (or all minus one) to be present
- `force_friction()` - This formula existed in two versions, but has now been joined into one as we can detect which field/argument is missing. This version uses the `fields` dictionary directly in the formulas, and test directly against which argument is missing
- `force_friction_v2()` – In version 2 of this formula, I use the default argument to set local variables which are then used in the formulas. This also allows for testing directly which arguments is missing as this is set to `None`
- `EQUATIONS` – This list is the pivot point to simplifying the `force()` functions. It is a list of all equations listed by function name and indexed by their id. In python you can now call the dereferenced function directly, and pass all arguments given to `force()` directly to that function. This moves the burden of argument checking to the actual function, and simplifies the structure of `force()` immensely as it no longer needs to differentiate between which `equation_id` matches which function, and which arguments goes to which function, and so on. It can no focus on running the general stuff related to calculating the functions
- `force_buyant()` – Is another way of checking for arguments, this time demanding that all are present, and thusly should be able to be called directly
- `force_centripetal()` - This is unchanged, and is just copied to display that if the arguments are correct this can be directly handled through the dereferencing method used. However if wrong arguments are used, it will fail somewhat more anonymously when picked up by adding a `except TypeError:` handling to `force()`.
- `force_friction_v3()` - Does *not* use the missing argument tests, but has named arguments where those possibly missing has a default value of `None`. This is the simplest decoration whilst still maintaining the possibility of allowing one field to be missing. It does however lack the possibility to tell end user which field was missing

### Conclusion

Using the construct `EQUATIONS[equation_id](**fields)` it is possible to simplify the `force()` function quite drastically. And then it is up to you if and how you want to decorate your functions, but you can rather easily move the burden of argument checking into the functions as demonstrated into the various versions of `force_friction()`, whilst still allowing for variable arguments to be used.

Personally I think I would opt for `force_friction_v2()` as it allows for precise error messages to be given when something is missing, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 4):

According to [PEP8](http://pep8online.com), Python's official style guide, your code has 255 violations of best practice, primarily cause of the extraneous whitespace:

> ```
> def force_given_ma( mass , acceleration ):
>     '''Returns the Force Given the Mass and the Acceleration'''
>     return ( mass * acceleration )
> ```

The extraneous whitespace violates best practice; it should look like this:

```
def force_given_ma(mass , acceleration):
    '''Returns the Force Given the Mass and the Acceleration'''
    return (mass * acceleration)
```

> ```
> accel   =         kwargs.get( 'acceleration' , 0 )
> charge  =         kwargs.get( 'charge' , 0 )
> charge2 =         kwargs.get( 'charge2' , 0 )
> dense   =         kwargs.get( 'density' , 0 )
> fcoeff  =         kwargs.get( 'friction_coefficient' , 0 )
> mass    =         kwargs.get( 'mass' , 0 )
> mass2   =         kwargs.get( 'mass2', 0 )
> moment  =         kwargs.get( 'momentum' , 0 )
> nForce  =         kwargs.get( 'normal_force' , 0 )
> radius  =         kwargs.get( 'radius' , 0 )
> time    =         kwargs.get( 'time' , 0 )
> veloc   =         kwargs.get( 'velocity' , 0 )
> volume  =         kwargs.get( 'volume' , 0 )
> ```

It may look really nice to indent everything like that, but it's just plain wrong.
And also, there shouldn't be a space before the comma in an argument list.

---

On a more technical note, the following can and should be improved:

> ```
> if equation_id == 1:
>     ret = force_bouyant( dense , volume )
> elif equation_id == 2:
>     ret = force_centripetal( mass, veloc, radius )
> elif equation_id == 3:
>     ret = force_electrical( charge , charge2, radius )
> elif equation_id == 4:
>     ret = force_gravity( mass , mass2 , radius )
> elif equation_id == 5:
>     if ( ( nForce == 0 ) and ( mass != 0 ) ):
>         ret = force_friction_nNF( mass , fcoeff )
>     elif ( nForce != 0 ):
>         ret = force_friction( nForce , fcoeff )
>     else:
>         raise E.InputError("No Normal Force Data was input")
> elif equation_id == 6:
>     ret = force_given_ma( mass, accel )
> elif equation_id == 7:
>     ret = force_given_pt( moment , time )
> else:
>     raise E.InputError("Invalid or No Equation Input")
> return ret
> ```

First, `ret` shouldn't need to be used, return the result directly.

Don't swap usage of `return` between in brackets and not.

The magic numbers in the `if-else` conditionals, should be moved to a dictionary.

Correct the grammar in all your doc strings and return messages, consider your usage of capitalisation and pronouns.

If you're working out one of a few equations, only generate the variables needed for that equation, don't generate all of them in a block.

Your usage of `E` and `C` as libraries is a little... misleading. Keep them as `Errors` and `Constants`, no need to simplify them.

Comment: "First, ret shouldn't need to be used, return the result directly." Can you explain why you would prefer multiple exit points to the function? Legitimately curious.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Although I am also curious as to why you think I should have multiple exit points in my function

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you want is something that looks like a [dsl](/questions/tagged/dsl) — a domain-specific language.  [Here](/a/47821/9357) is an example of a similar problem solved in Ruby.  You can draw inspiration from it, though you cannot translate the code directly into Python.

Applied to equation 3 (which you should call Coulomb's Law, since "electrical force" is too vague), a calculation could look like this:

```
CoulombsLaw(q1=0.0002, q2=0.00013, r=0.5).f
```

The code to support that syntax might look like this:

```
import C
import math

class CoulombsLaw:
    def __init__(self, f=None, q1=None, q2=None, r=None):
        self._f = f
        self._q1 = q1
        self._q2 = q2
        self._r = r

    @property
    def f(self):
        return C.COULOMB_CONSTANT * self._q1 * self._q2 / (self._r * self._r)

    @property
    def q1(self):
        return self._f * self._r * self._r / (C.COULOMB_CONSTANT * self._q2)

    @property
    def q2(self):
        return self._f * self._r * self._r / (C.COULOMB_CONSTANT * self._q1)

    @property
    def r(self):
        return math.sqrt(C.COULOMB_CONSTANT * self._q1 * self._q2 / self._f)
```

This is just one way to do it.  I hope it gives you some ideas.